# Classic ASP form not working in Opera, Chrome, or Firefox (but does in IE)

Tags: forms, firefox, google-chrome, asp-classic, opera

I'm working with a Classic ASP site and having a bit of a conundrum... my form works perfectly in IE, but in Chrome, Opera, and Firefox I can't click anything within the form - I can't type or even get a cursor to show up in the input fields, the link isn't clickable and neither is the button.  The mouse pointer doesn't even change on mouseover of any of those elements.

The doctype is HTML 4.01 Strict, and I have validated it with the W3 validator.  The links in the page's header and footer are clickable as normal.

```
<form name="esi" method="post" action="employeehome.asp">
<p>
    <label for="empid" class="achtung">Employee ID:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="empid" size="20" maxlength="30">
</p>
<p>
    <label for="emppw" class="achtung">Password:</label><br>
    <input type="password" name="emppw" size="20" maxlength="20"><br>
    <a href="emppwrecovery.asp" class="txtfsz10">Password Recovery</a>
</p>
<p>
    <input type="hidden" name="empstatus" value="1">
</p>
<p class="submitbuttonspace">
    <input type="submit" value="Sign In">
</p>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you duplicate this on a jsfiddle?

Comment: Specially add any css or js you have in that page

Comment: I don't have any javascript in the page (also I'm not sure what jsfiddle is!  Sorry).  I did just check the css after I remembered the form was nested in a div... I took out the float: left and that did the trick.  I had no idea that would affect the form that way... thank you for the css suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with this form example. I just tested it on my server. No errors and nothing to disable anything.

You must have something else crashing your browser.